# Как удалить обычное сообщение в inline режиме в боте

Tags: python, telegram-bot, inline

Попытался отследить id и удалить сообщение, но мне возвращает Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: message identifier is not specified

```
        @bot.message_handler(commands="start")
        def send_message(message):
            keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('test', callback_data='test'))
            bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text='Test', reply_markup=keyboard)
            msgId = message.message_id

        @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
        def callback_inline(call):
            if call.data == "test":
                img = open('1.jpg', 'rb')
                keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
                keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('back', callback_data='back'))
                bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, 
        message_id=call.message.message_id, text='Test1' )
                bot.send_photo(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, photo=img, reply_markup=keyboard)

            if call.data == 'back':
                if call.message.text == 'Test':
                    bot.delete_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, 
        message_id=call.message.message_id)
                keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
                keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('test1', callback_data='test'))
                bot.delete_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=msgId)
                bot.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, text='Test 2', reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#updating-messages вот здесь посмотрите

Comment: Спасибо. С обновлениями я +- разобрался. Возможно как нибудь отслеживать id сообщений, чтобы потом их чистить / обновлять? Насколько я понял телеграм дает изменить последнее отправленное сообщение

Comment: сохраняйте в БД  id сообщений, а уже потом удаляйте их.

Comment: спасибо, попробую

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1365572/467311 вот здесь я попытался это реализовать на C#